# Autocomplete Angular, no se realiza el autocompletado correctamente al agregar más elementos

Tags: angular

Desde ya hace algunos días vengo con este problema, pero aún no he logrado encontrar la solución. Estoy usando ***myControl[index]*** para que los datos no se repitan al agregar más inputs. El problema es que en el primer input hace el autocompletado correctamente, pero sin embrago al agregar más inputs ya no me funciona el autocompletado. 
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme con esto, estaré muy agradecido.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el Link aquí https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xhejm6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    listUsers:Array<any>;

cuando envias parametros se hace de la siguiente manera

busquedaDescripcionProductoAutocompletado() {
let descripcion= '';
    const index = this.arregloCuadroTextoDescripcionDetalle.findIndex(indice => indice.value === descripcion);
    this.myControl[index].valueChanges.subscribe(descripcionUser => {
  descripcion=descripcionUser;
        this.userService.listUsers(descripcion).subscribe(response => {
          this.listUsers = response['data'];
        }, error => {
    console.log('Error del servidor. Por favor contácte con soporte o intente más tarde.');
        });
    });
  }
```